# jQuery function in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm one of those people who never was bother to learn JavaScript and went straight for jQuery.

I'm writing simple script to hide everything till page is fully loaded - and because my jQuery is loaded after html/css/images I planning to put small script in the header.

So in jQuery it would be

```
$('body').css('display','none');
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.body.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

But than:

```
$(window).load(function() { $('body').css('display', 'block').fadeIn(3000); });
```

Has not animation? Why?

**What I'm trying to do:**

- #1 hide everything(body) with javascipt till everything is loaded (there is no jQuery at this state as is being loaded at the end)
- #2 show everthing(body) with animation of fadding (with jQuery - as is loaded at this state)

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Comment: Your hiding the html element in your pure javascript example...

Comment: jQuery and Javascript are not distinct languages. If you're coding with jQuery (a library of convenience functions, nothing more) then you are coding in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to

```
$('body').css('display','none');
```

is

```
document.body.style.display = 'none';
```

`$('body')` selects the `body` element, but `document.body.parentNode` obviously selects the parent of `body`.

<s>And shouldn't it be just</s>

```
$('body').fadeIn(3000);
```

?

I asked because I assumed you already got the code working with only jQuery. But apparently you haven't, so again, it has to be `$('body').fadeIn(3000);` only, otherwise you make the element visible immediately and there is nothing to animate anymore.

See a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Q24pC/1/

**Update:**

`$(window).load` is only triggered when the all resources are loaded. This could take longer if you have images. To hide the elements earlier, you should listen to the `ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // still don't know why you don't want to use jQuery.
    document.body.style.display = 'none';
});
```

or hide the elements initially with CSS

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

To make sure that users with disabled JavaScript can see the page, you'd have to add

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        body {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

in the `head` after you other CSS styles.

**Update 2**

Seems that setting the CSS property directly causes problems in some browsers. But using `$('body').hide()` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/JaLZU/

Comment: When using `document.body.style.display = 'none';` FireBug through an error with `document.body is null` .. ?

Comment: @Pete: Well, you can only run the code after the document loaded. Have a look at the demo, the code is inside the callback.

Comment: @Felix Kling What I'm trying to do: #1 hide everthing with .js till page is fully loaded (with javascript because jquery is loaded at the end) #2 show with animation after everything and jquery is loaded

Comment: @Pete: Why is jQuery loaded at the end? Why don't you include the script in the `head`? You can only hide the elements when they are available. And `body` is only available after the whole DOM was built. Your best option is then to hide them with CSS I think.

Comment: @Felix Kling  This solutions works only in Chrome. with `<noscript><style type="text/css"> body { display: block; } </style></noscript>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(window).load(function() { 
   $('body').fadeIn(3000); 
 });
</script>` in the head

Comment: @Pete: Yeah, just tried. Don't know why it dies not work with CSS. Well, then hide the `body` with jQuery.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I would do that - but as it is business project for office workers - we are expecting some non-js users..

Comment: @Pete: So? If you hide the page with jQuery, then it will not be hidden for those who disabled JS. I don't get the point...

Comment: @Felix Kling  Sorry, got confused. Again:            `$(document).ready(function() {     $('body').css('display','none');
  });
  $(window).load( function() {
   $('body').fadeIn(1000); 
  });` will work on Chrome only! :/

Comment: @Pete: Maybe it is a problem with `display: none`. Use `$('body').hide()` instead. Worked for me in Firefox.

Comment: @Felix Kling - `$('body').hide()` works in FF, nothing pleased the IE though :/ Guess will live it without animations - as is not cross-browser at all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that clear on what your question really is, but if I'm on the right track you don't need the `.css('display', 'block')` part for the animation. Get rid of that, so it's just `$('body').fadeIn(3000);` and the animation should work fine.

Comment: Not with `document.body.parentNode.style.display = 'none';`: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Q24pC/